# Prevent change in struct pointer values while testing

Tags: pointers, go

How do I prevent any change done to struct values to remain in a subtest only i.e. to keep them unaffected outside the subtest. I can't make any changes in the structs as they are autogenerated using swagger codegen. Here is an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestTyre(t *testing.T) {
    type Tyre struct {
        Color *string
    }
    type Vehicle struct {
        Tyre Tyre
    }

    color := "black"
    tyreForTest := Tyre{Color: &color}
    expectedTyreColor := color

    t.Run("negativeTest", func(t *testing.T) {
        tyre := tyreForTest               // would have worked if there weren't any pointer variables
        *tyre.Color = "blue"              // here I expect value to change only for this subtest

        vehicle := Vehicle{Tyre: tyre}
        actualTyreColor := vehicle.Tyre.Color

        ok := (expectedTyreColor == *actualTyreColor)
        if ok {
            t.Error("Color should be blue")
        }
    })
    t.Run("positiveTest", func(t *testing.T) {
        tyre := tyreForTest

        vehicle := Vehicle{Tyre: tyre}
        actualTyreColor := vehicle.Tyre.Color

        ok := (expectedTyreColor == *actualTyreColor)
        if !ok {
            t.Error("Color should be black, instead of", *actualTyreColor)
        }
    })
}
```

Output:

```
=== RUN   TestTyre
=== RUN   TestTyre/negativeTest
=== RUN   TestTyre/positiveTest
    TestTyre/positiveTest: prog.go:39: Color should be black, instead of blue
--- FAIL: TestTyre (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestTyre/negativeTest (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestTyre/positiveTest (0.00s)
FAIL
```

Comment: You can't prevent that. Just don't share variables.

Comment: Manually create a copy of color and assign the address of the copy as the pointer field. There also ought to be 3rd party packages on github that implement deepcopy if you're not inclined to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You prevent that by not sharing `color` variable between test cases - each of your test cases gets a new `Tyre` but they both point to same memory storing color value. So, when you change `tyre.Color` in negative test case you update value of variable `color` and other test case `tyre.Color` points to that variable too.

Simple solution would be having a function `makeTyre()` that gets completely new Tyre with its own memory to store color and obtain Tyre for each test case:

```golang
package main

import (
        "testing"
)

type Tyre struct {
        Color *string
}
type Vehicle struct {
        Tyre Tyre
}

func makeTyre() Tyre {
        color := "black"
        return Tyre{Color: &color}
}

func TestTyre(t *testing.T) {
        expectedTyreColor := "black"

        t.Run("negativeTest", func(t *testing.T) {
                tyre := makeTyre()
                *tyre.Color = "blue"
                vehicle := Vehicle{Tyre: tyre}
                actualTyreColor := vehicle.Tyre.Color

                ok := (expectedTyreColor == *actualTyreColor)
                if ok {
                        t.Error("Color should be blue")
                }
        })
        t.Run("positiveTest", func(t *testing.T) {
                tyre := makeTyre()

                vehicle := Vehicle{Tyre: tyre}
                actualTyreColor := vehicle.Tyre.Color

                ok := (expectedTyreColor == *actualTyreColor)
                if !ok {
                        t.Error("Color should be black, instead of", *actualTyreColor)
                }
        })
}
```